# Using watir-webdriver, can I change the driver temporarily?

Tags: cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

Can I change the driver temporarily. Basically I have Phantomjs setup as my default driver but need to use a different driver for 1 feature. The issue is, Phantomjs cannot find a certain element on a page as it is hidden, but on a normal browser it shows perfectly fine and feature passes with no issues.

If anyone has come across the need to temporarily change driver and has a solution, please let me know.

Comment: Why can't you just reinitialize browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tags to specify scenarios that should use a specific browser/driver.

For example, you could have the following in your env.rb:

```
require 'watir'

Before('~@firefox') do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs 
end

# Use the firefox browser 
Before('@firefox') do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
end

After do
    @browser.close
end
```

During your scenarios/features that are tagged with @firefox, they will use the firefox browser. Otherwise, they will use your default phantomjs driver.

Comment: Thanks Justin, i'll give this a go and get back if it works. Looks like a good solution, so i'm pretty confident. Once again thanks.